# Unity - lean touch move objects on z axis instead of y?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Ok, Im using Lean Touch from the asset store and I can move objects in x and y directions. The objects have gravity affected rigid bodies and so will fall to a plane. When they are on a plane, (like in AR) I need vertical finger movement to move the object on the z axis.

I dont know how to do this. This is where the transform occurs:

```
//REAL TRANSLATE
        protected virtual void Translate(Vector2 screenDelta)
        {
            // Make sure the camera exists
            var camera = LeanTouch.GetCamera(Camera, gameObject);

            if (camera != null)
            {
                // Screen position of the transform
                var screenPoint = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

                // Add the deltaPosition
                screenPoint += (Vector3)screenDelta;

                transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
```

This is in LeanTranslate.cs. How can I move the object on z axis instead of y (ideally IF it contacts a plane)?

NOW:

```
  if(transform.GetComponent<ObjectController>() != null && transform.GetComponent<ObjectController>().isOnPlane)
                {

                    Vector3 newDelta = new Vector3(screenDelta.x, 0, screenDelta.y*0.05f);
                    screenPoint += newDelta;

                } else {
                    screenPoint += (Vector3)screenDelta;
                }


                transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
```

ERROR:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right now the code just casts the screenDelta variable to a Vector3.  This is roughly equivalent to "new Vector3(screenDelta.x, screenDelta.y, 0)", which leaves the z-axis zeroed.

So, you just need to replace that line with a custom one that assigns the delta to the correct axes.

Comment: Thanks, my only problem is it now moves on the z axis TOWARDS the camera, y doesn't stay the same (the object should stay level with the plane, instead it rushes towards the camera). See my edit

Comment: The current code is trying to project the position from screen space to world space.  It sounds like you just want to work in world space.  I would remove the last line, and just push the object relatively by the delta in the mouse position, substituting z for y.

Comment: So you mean do transform.position = screenPoint; ? That gave me an infinite error (posted above)

Comment: No, you would need to track the delta of the mouse, the offset per frame, and transform that into world coordinates that would be added to the transform.position in a way that feels good in your game.

Comment: Ok, sorry I don't know what you mean by offset per frame. Would you post an example with code? Im a little lost

Comment: Something like transform.position += new Vector3(screenDelta.x, 0, screenDelta.y);